# How can i stop my app from getting back to splash screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building a simple ordering app with a splash screen , and i'm having trouble on making the app to not go back on the splash screen ,I have tried a conditional operator to solve the problem, but its not doing anything, is there any other alternatives to achieve that??

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:propapp/tabs/main.dart';
import 'dart:async';

bool loaded = false;

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.amber,
      accentColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: loaded == true ? Menu() : SplashScreen()));

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => new _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Menu()),
            ));
    loaded = true;
      }


}
```

Comment: Hey, if you are trying to stop you app from going back to `SplashScreen` anytime you open it, you should consider SharedPrefs

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Navigator.pushReplacement`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html). Remove your condition again:

```
...
home: SplashScreen()));
```

And the only other change will be replacing `Navigator.push` with `pushReplacement`:

```
... => Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Menu()),
            )
```

This will remove the `SplashScreen` route from the navigator stack and thus never go back to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful plugin in https://pub.dartlang.org called `SplashScreen` will offer you this functionality and other ones like a splash timer, here's the link:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/splashscreen